# Using WWW to load External Music Files issue Yield Not Returning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is for the newest version of unity 4.6.1f1 (i've also posted the question on the unity forums - so will update if get given answers)

I've been trying to use WWW to load local and external music from a full file path location.
I have found various examples including the linked stack overflow question below (along side other examples). However they all seem to fail on the loading of the music.
[How to play sounds loaded on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948046/how-to-play-sounds-loaded-on-the-fly)

The problem that occurs is that the process simply never get's out of this statement which suggests it never loads.

```
while (!myAudioClip.isReadyToPlay)
       yield return www;
```

I have tried with multiple examples but yet it always gets stuck at the same part of the process.
The link I am passing it can extract Id3 tags so I assume that path is correct.

Is there any known issues or fixes for using WWW in unity 4? Or are there any alternative functions/classes for loading?

Other Examples/Information looked at:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/449101/can-i-replace-an-audio-clip-with-a-user-selected-f.html

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks